# Do KeyEvents work like interrupts?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program right now where a loop is exited based on a variable I set in a KeyEvent. 
Here's how it looks

```
while(System.nanoTime() - startTime < 3000000000L) // 3 second timer
        {
            if(rightPressed)
                break;
        }
```

Then, in the key listener I do the following:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        if(repeatCheck)
            return;

        rightPressed = true; 
        repeatCheck = true;
        if(matchRight)
            score++;
        else
            score = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the loop never exits before the 3 seconds are up, even if I push the right arrow key, but the "score" variable will update accordingly. I'm more familiar with embedded systems, so will a keyevent interrupt the currently running thread? Or how do they work?

Comment: what is `repeatCheck`

Comment: It won't matter once I have this figured out -- right now it's just making sure pressing right over and over and over in the 3 second timer doesn't continuously increment the score.

Answer (score 0):

change your while loop to have  multiple conditions so you can get rid of the 
if condition inside the while loop.

```
while(System.nanoTime() - startTime < 3000000000L && !rightPressed)
```

inside the `keyEvent` . you are checking `repeatcheck` if the value is `true` rest of the `codes` won't be executed because of the `return` statement. which means `rightpressed` will never be true. change your code within `keyevent` to

```
        rightPressed = true; 
        repeatCheck = true;
        if(matchRight){
            score++;
        }else{
            score = 0;
        }
        if(repeatCheck){
         return;
        }
```

since you are working on  a `thread` it is possible that your `thread` is `executed` first before you press the `right` key use  `thread.sleep()` in your thread which will give you some time to press the `right key`.

Comment: I think is another problem because he said that score was increasing. If score increases it means that it passes repeatCheck. I was thinking about threading problem maybe. I think that variable runs in two threads.

Comment: Moving repeat check below won't matter. I initialize it to false, so it's always false the first time the code runs. The only time it's true is when the  key event has already successfully run once, and then it's reset to false later. This isn't the problem, because I can get the score variable to the correct value using this code.

Comment: Consolidating the if into the while works and is probably good practice, but doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: try synchronization on that variable when changing its value. Maybe is it.

Comment: its just a matter of `3 seconds` . are you `pressing` the right key as soon as system startup  . try using a `thread.sleep()` inside the thread. who knows your `thread` finish `executing` before you press the `right key.` and mark the variable as `static` if you are not sure about the `variables` being shared by two conditions